# JSF 2.0/Facelets - JavaScript characters get encoded as html entities

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, facelets

I'm using jQuery inside Faceletes template. The problem is that special characters are encoded as html entities, eg `if (y >= top) {` to `if (y &gt;= top) {`

I'm using JSF 2.0 with Glassfish 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  //your script here
//]]>
</script>
```